# PHP cache an entire external website

Tags: php, caching, iframe

I'm currently using `iframes` to showcase several external client websites on my site, like this site here http://progressionstudios.com/themes-wp/?theme=Stoken

The problem is that the client websites are located really far away from my server and my site visitors and can take a long time to load. I'm trying to cache each website into `html` files which I can then reference in the `iframe` URL.

However I'm still quite new to `php` and my question is, does this method cache the entire external website or only the page I'm pointing to?

If not are there methods which will allow me to cache an entire external website? Alternatively, does caching one page mean that all the `CSS/js` files are cached so that any other pages only load the difference in content?

Sorry if my question sounds basic/amateur, but I haven't found any other sources which can answer my question or is in a similar situation to me.

Comment: what method are you talking about? you can save the html source code but you have to save the js/css as well and change the source if the js/css is loaded with an absolute url e.g. `http://www.site.com/style.css`. Oh and the images of cource..you have to save them too. I think it's a bad idea all in all.

Comment: can't I add a base URL to the document and have everything referred externally? I only want to cache the content.

Comment: but if the html content takes long to load than the images, css and js files takes long, too. And the subpages? You want to cache the whole sitetree?

Comment: @redreggae yea basically everything takes a while to load and also the external website's server has a pretty slow upload speed. Is it possible to cache the whole sitetree?

Comment: everything is possible..the question is if it's really necessary and not a total overkill. So build your self a search engine that automatically scrapes the whole sitetree and change all sitelinks in source to your cached html files. Why not make screenshots of the sites and link them? Don't you think this is a better idea?

Comment: well taking a screenshot and linking it doesn't reduce the speed issue which is really slow. I know I can use wget to basically download their whole site but what about updates and site refreshes? I need to have my users able to view the sites in an acceptable speed whilst also maintaining site freshness.